# Space key to send " " (no-break space) when CapsLock state is Down, otherwise send regular space in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to send a non-break space ( ) through `Space` key *only* when CapsLock is On, ootherwise send the regular space key.

I've tried a bunch of different variations of the following but none of them exactly work right.

```
$~Space::
    GetKeyState, state, CapsLock, T
    if state = D
        send, { } ; non-break space
    else
        send, { } ; regular space
    Return
```

It seems to either always send the regular space (`$~`, or only `~`) or not send it at all (only `$`), or not work at all (neither `$` or `~`).

Here's a list different variations of `$`/`~` literals I've use with respective results:

For convenience, I'll pretend I want to use the character `n` instead of non-break space.

Keeping the above code same except the first line, on pressing the Space key:

- `$~Space::`

  - caps lock off: Sends `<space>` (good)
  - caps lock on: Sends `<space>n` (why the extra space?)

- `$Space::`

  - caps lock off: Sends nothing!
  - caps lock on: Sends `n` (good)

- `~Space::`

  - caps lock off: Sends `<space>` (good)
  - caps lock on: Sends `<space>n` (why the extra space?)

- `Space::`

  - caps lock off: Sends nothing!
  - caps lock on: Sends `n` (good)

What's the correct way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using ahk 1.1+ from http://ahkscript.org

try this:

```
#if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
$space::send n
return
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Perfect! Sidenote: It takes another `#if` to end the conditional

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**Version 1:**

```
$~Space::

    if (GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") = 1)
    {
       send, { } ; non-break space 
    }
    else
    {
       send, { } ; regular space
    }

return
```

**Version 2:**

```
$~Space::

    if (GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") = 1)
    {
       Send, {Backspace}
       send, { } ; non-break space 
    }
    else
    {
       send, { } ; regular space
    }

return
```

<kbd>Capslock</kbd> state checking works fine in my code. I dont know what is different between regular and nonregular spaces (I coped `Send` commands from your code "as is"), so please check if correct space is send.

Advices:

1. Use `GetKeyState` built in function instead of command.
2. Always put `if` statement condition in `()` .
3. Always use include `if` statement body in `{}` .
4. Always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!

Comment: This too sends two spaces (`<nb-space><reg-space>`) when it should send just `<nb-space>`. You can use any character (like "n") instead of nb-space. It sends `<n><space>` when caps lock is down.

Comment: Capslock checking is working fine in my original code as well. The problem is it's always either sending the regular space along with the nb-space or not sending the regular space altogether.

Comment: @laggingreflex Try **Version 2**. I think it does what you need.